# How to filter bad records while writing to a RDS (Postgre) table via Glue ETL job

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-glue-spark

I am doing Glue ETL processing which basically does the following -

1. Read a file from S3 (via Glue Catalog)
2. Transfer the data (add/delete columns)
3. Write data to RDS postgre table (Also via Glue Catalog)

```
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', 'SRC_DB', 'SRC_TABLE', 'TGT_DB', 'TGT_TABLE'])

DataSource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = args['SRC_DB'], table_name = args['SRC_TABLE'], transformation_ctx = "DataSource0")

Transform0 = sparkSqlQuery(glueContext, query = SqlQuery0, mapping = {"sparkDataSource": DataSource0}, transformation_ctx = "Transform0")

DataSink0 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(frame = Transform0, database = args['TGT_DB'], table_name = args['TGT_TABLE'], transformation_ctx = "DataSink0")
```

What I want to achieve here is to filter out bad records (for example - in any record for one of the column, if data value length is more than the length defined in the data catalog or RDS table)  and insert those records to some other table or S3 file and continue the processing without the exception. So that I can report the bad records to the source team.,

What happening here is if there is any bad data (column data type or length mismatch) after transform, the glue ETL job is getting aborted with the Batch Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below approach to solve this problem:

1. Use Glue map.apply with an UDF where you can pass dynamic record and calculate the length as new column. Once done you can return the dynamic frame with additional record. Refer to this link for example of UDF.

   ````
      d["date"] = datetime.today() 
      return d 
      datasource1 = Map.apply(frame = datasource0, f = addDate)```
   ````
2. Now use Glue `splitrows` transformation to achieve this by passing the length column to comparison_dict. Below is an example with conditions and return two dynamic frames as collection depending on the condition.

```
dyf_splitRows = SplitRows.apply(frame = dyf_dropNullfields, comparison_dict = {"`data.pineapple`": {">": "100", 
    "<": "200"}}, name1 = 'pa_200_less', name2 = 'pa_200_more')
```